# Moq not running correctly and always gives wrong result

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq

I created a small test project in VS 2022 -> .Net framework 4.7.2 to check the usage of moq.
Interface and the implementation are provided below.

```
public interface IDataMaintainer
{
    bool AddData();
    bool RemoveData();
    bool DoSomething();
}

public abstract class DataMaintainer : IDataMaintainer
{
    public virtual bool AddData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual bool RemoveData()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual bool DoSomething()
    {
        AddData();
        RemoveData();
        return true;
    }

    public virtual string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I used the NUnit V3.13.3 and installed Moq via nuget package manager (last stable v4.20.69). My test methods are furnished below

```
[Test]
public void MockTest3()
{
    //using moq library
    Mock<DataMaintainer> chk = new Mock<DataMaintainer>();
    chk.Setup(x => x.AddData()).Returns(true);
    Assert.That(chk.Object.DoSomething(), Is.EqualTo(false));
}
```

DoSomething() will return true. As a result of this, the Assert() should fail as i am checking for False.
But in my case, the tests are always passing.

[image: Moq tests]
Any idea about this issue? What information do you require to check it in detail?

ps: with earlier version of Moq also i get same result.

Looking forward to your suggestions,
TIA

Comment: Mock the interface, not the class.

Comment: DoSomething has a hard Coded 'return true` and ignores what is returned from AddData.  So why should it ever return something else then true?

Comment: Oh Sorry. You are NOT expecting something else.

Answer (score 2):

When you mock an interface or class, you're not creating an instance of it. Think about it, how could you even create an instance of an abstract class anyway?

So in your case, the `DoSomething` method isn't actually internally calling `AddData` or returning `true` as you see in your abstract class, it's just giving you the default value for `bool` which is `false`. You should instead be mocking the `DoSomething` method, e.g.:

```
chk.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).Returns (true);
```

Comment: If would say the mock is a derived instance of it. But as DoSomething is virtual it gets automatically mocked because he uses a loose mock. A strict mock should bark here that  DoSomething isn't implemented in the mock. Removing virtual from DoSomething should make his Testcode work. And with working its not that i think the result shows good testable code.

Comment: @Ralf Sorry, you are right, you should add that as an answer and I'll delete this one.

Comment: Actually i'm more of a commenter type then an answerer type of user here and added my comment here instead of the question in the hopes you feel urged to improve your answer ;)

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for your fast feedback.  indeed, i can mock doSomething() and that perfectly fine. but i am wondering how can i verify the result of the above method and make an Assert?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have mocked the `DataMaintainer` instead of the `IDataMaintainer` you can ask Moq to execute the "original" code with the following command:

```
chk.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).CallBase();
```

Please bear in mind that this will call the "original" code **ONLY** for the `DoSomething`. So, your `AddData` will not throw an exception since you have mocked it to return true.

With this line your test would fail as you have expected.